# How to re download old emails from Server to Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook, pop3, outlook-2007

I configure email in outlook 2007. we are using our own domain email. I want to download all the emails from server. But it is not downloading. we are using Pop3.

I tried **Send/Receiveall** but not downloading. I have 10000 emails on server. but it just showing current emails only

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that those e-mails no longer exist on the server. In most cases I've seen, the client-server system work like this: e-mail are only temporary stored on the server until you start your Outlook client. By default, Outlook deletes messages from the server after it retrieves them when configured as a POP3 client. At that point, they are gone from the server and exist only on the client. The exception to this is if you used initially 'keep e-mails on the server for X days' option of Outlook. In that case, the e-mails will stick around on the server for the amount of days specified in the setting.

Comment: I have my old email on my server right now. It's not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Are these messages still in your Inbox folder on the POP3 server?

POP3 accounts only allow to download everything from the Inbox folder. If your mails are in any other folder on-line, you'll need to move them back to the Inbox first.

Besides, you can pull down your emails by exporting the mailbox contents to a PST. Here's the instruction https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/783

Comment: Hi, how's going on with your problem now? Has it been fixed?